# Comparing pre/post percentage change between pairs of random samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, modeling, case-control-study, intervention-analysis

I am studying cycling rates along a street that recently received a bike lane. The data I have consists of 4 random samples of people intersected on the sidewalk. For each person, we know if they rode their bike to the retail strip. We have before and after samples in the case study area (bike lane added), as well as before and after samples in a control study area (no bike lane added).

Each of the 4 samples are independent from one another. In other words, we do not track whether an individual who was sampled before changes their behavior after.  Rather, we have 400 responses before in each study area, and 400 responses after in each study.  Very easy to compare any pair of these means with a difference of proportion test.  But, how can we tell if the pre/post change in cycling rates was greater in the case area compared to the change observed in the control area?  I know how to do this if we observe the pre/post behavior for the same individuals, but our pre and our post cycling rates are coming from two different samples.